# Rails 3: delete not targeting the right controller action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a tickets resource that contains comments.
The comments show up on the tickets show page, but when I click delete for each comment, it takes me to the show for the comments controller.

This is the delete code:

```
<h2>Comments</h2> 
<% @ticket.comments.each do |comment| %>   
  <p>
    <b>Commenter:</b>
    <%= comment.commenter %>   
  </p>
  <p>
    <b>Comment:</b>
    <%= comment.body %>   
  </p>  
  <%= link_to 'Delete', [@project, @ticket, comment], :confirm => "Sure", :method => delete, :remote => true %> 
<% end %>
```

I don't think it is connected to the comments#destroy action cause it is on the comments#show action.   A little confused on how to go about this...
Thanks

Comment: Do you really have `:method => delete` in the link line? Not `:delete`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you have `[@project, @ticket, comment]` as the link location.

Assuming that the model associations are correct, I think if you just pass the comment then the link will automatically find the correct controller?

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', comment, :confirm => "Sure", :method => :delete, :remote => true %>
```

Comment: Got it to work, I used a named route to get it to delete.  I still used the [@project, @ticket, comment].